# More B-Smooth found at $(\left\lceil\sqrt{xN}\right\rceil)^2 \mod N$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

When $N$ is the number you want to factor and you are implementing the [quadratic sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) you are searching for b-smooth values at

$$f(x) = (\left\lceil\sqrt{N}\right\rceil + x)^2 \mod N$$

Instead of this, I tried to search them at here

$$h(x) = (\left\lceil\sqrt{xN}\right\rceil)^2 \mod N$$

With prime base of the size $1000$, when factoring a relatively small values of $42$ digits I came to the next result

```
f(x) 1.412: Processed 11,657,159 B-Smooth found 17 Big primes found 3
h(x) 9.786: Processed 104,965    B-Smooth found 3  Big primes found 30
```

At the first line you see that after $1.412$ seconds I processed $11,657,159$ values and found $17$ b-smooth values and $3$ big primes(another b-smooth values found by [big prime optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#Large_primes))

And when searching in $h(X)$ I found more relations(b-smooth and big primes) while processing $100$ times **less** numbers. It took me how ever much longer. This is because I couldn't use the sieving optimization of quadratic sieve, and I made the test in Java. Java use BigIntegers that mutable and therefore not efficient for such calculations.

Do you think that this method could be more efficient than **quadratic sieve** if implemented properly? What optimizations can you suggest me to test?